# how i can filter firestore by string contains value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

how i  can  filter data in
firebase containing characters
for example i want use
'''
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("table").where(
'my filed name ',
Contains: my_value ,
)
'''
my filed name  not  array
thanks for any help

Comment: You cannot query Firestore based on a substring. For small data sets might work but if you need that, then you should consider implementing a [third-party library](https://extensions.dev/extensions?category=search).

Comment: thanks for  answer   
do you know how i can  use or value  because 2 where not  working  as or